# How to update weights and biases

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to write a neural-network with numpy from scratch for recognizing hand_written_digits.but I'm little bit confused in updating weights and biases

here is my code

```
class NeuralNetwork():

    learning_rate = 0.0001
    ephochs = 10000
    nodes_in_input_layer = 784  # features
    nodes_in_hidden_layer = 100
    nodes_in_output_layer = 10  # classes
    np.random.seed(3)


    def __init__(self):
        self.hidden_layer = {'weights': np.random.rand(self.nodes_in_input_layer, self.nodes_in_hidden_layer)*0.1,
                             'biases': np.random.rand(self.nodes_in_hidden_layer)*0.1 }

        self.output_layer = {'weights': np.random.rand(self.nodes_in_hidden_layer, self.nodes_in_output_layer)*0.1,
                             'biases': np.random.rand(self.nodes_in_output_layer)*0.1 }

        print('self.hidden_layer: ',self.hidden_layer['weights'].shape)
        print('self.output_layer: ',self.output_layer['weights'].shape)

    def fit(self, x, y, ephochs= ephochs):
        for i in range(ephochs):
            # feed forword
            z_hidden_layer = np.dot(x[i], self.hidden_layer['weights']) + self.hidden_layer['biases']
            o_hidden_layer = sigmoid(z_hidden_layer)

            z_output_layer = np.dot(o_hidden_layer, self.output_layer['weights']) + self.output_layer['biases']
            o_output_layer = sigmoid(z_output_layer)

            # back propagation
            error = o_output_layer - y[i]

            '''
            ## at output layer 

            derror_dweights = derror/do * do/dz * dz/dw

            derror/do = error
            do/dz = derivative of sigmoid(x[i]) 
            dz/dw = o_hidden_layer
            ''' 
            derror_do = error 
            do_dz =  sigmoid(z_output_layer, derivative=True)
            dz_dw =  o_hidden_layer

            nw_output_layer = derror_do * do_dz
            nw_output_layer = np.dot(nw_output_layer, dz_dw.T) 

            nb_output_layer = error

            # updating new weights and biases
            self.output_layer['weights'] = self.output_layer['weights'] - (self.learning_rate * nw_output_layer)
            self.output_layer['biases'] = self.output_layer['biases'] - (self.learning_rate * nb_output_layer)

            ## update remain weights and biases
```

while I'm running i got this error

`nw_output_layer = np.dot(nw_output_layer, dz_dw.T) 
ValueError: shapes (10,) and (100,) not aligned: 10 (dim 0) != 100 (dim 0)`

can anyone explain the process of updating weights and biases of this neural-network in step-by-step?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. First, you might want to correct the error (dimensions of your arrays do not match). Then, you might want to go into the deep-learning concepts deeper.

Comment: thank you! yeah, that's what I'm asking. where i went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In neural network, you have to preprocess your data into same shape. You can try to preprocess data inside function. So that, you have to simply call the same function to preprocess the test data. This will prevent getting diffetent shape for differemnt data.

The weights are updated to measure hyperplanes for separating data. For example,

In binary classification you fill find line with slope for separating two classes with line equation Y = MX + B. The same way you need to separate multidimensional data with hyperplane by gradient descent algorithm.

W = W - learning rate * delta

Here the delta is partial derivatives of loss. By updating weights you can reduce loss. At a certain point the loss will reach some local minima. At this point (local minima) stop the epochs (number of iterations to find best accuracy).

For updating weights you can use for loop with some batch size. In neural network you have to find learning rate and epochs that suits your data. If you are using very less learning rate, it will slow down your training.

Comment: First I thought that add mini batch gradient decent later, try basic model first.but implemented after your answer. Everything is fine now. Thanks you